# Checkmarx Code Quality Warning

Tags: apex, bulkification, checkmarx

After running a Checkmarx scan it returned a code quality warning on a method due to Query: Bulkify Apex Methods Using Collections In Methods.

The method is very simple:

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static String saveDSAM(List<inscor__Data_Service_Account_Mapping__c> dsamList, List<inscor__Customer_Quote__c> cqList) {
    Savepoint sp = database.setSavepoint();
    try {
        if (!Schema.sObjectType.inscor__Data_Service_Account_Mapping__c.isCreateable() ||
                !Schema.sObjectType.inscor__Customer_Quote__c.isUpdateable()) {
                throw new NoAccessException();
        }
        insert dsamList;
        update cqList;
        return 'SUCCESS';
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        system.debug('-Exception-'+ex+'-'+ex.getStackTraceString());
        return 'Error~'+ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

It is passed a list of two sObjects and updates, inserts one list and updates another. The line number the scan returns is when the cqList is updated.

```
Object: cqlist in file: classes/quote360Controller.cls
L 555: public static String saveDSAM(List<inscor__Data_Service_Account_Mapping__c> dsamList, List<inscor__Customer_Quote__c> cqList) {
Object: cqlist in file: classes/quote360Controller.cls
L 563: update cqList;
```

I thought by modifying the method parameters to be lists that it would resolve this issue. This method is called by a lightning component and is never call in iteration. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly a false positive, although it may simply be complaining since your code does not explicitly handle the case where `dsamList` throws an error. I would advise simply ignoring this warning, or possibly reaching out to Checkmarx Support directly to find out why this error would have been generated. The only change I would recommend is to use the appropriate use of [AuraHandledException](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html):

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void saveDSAM(List<inscor__Data_Service_Account_Mapping__c> dsamList, List<inscor__Customer_Quote__c> cqList) {
    try {
        if (!Schema.sObjectType.inscor__Data_Service_Account_Mapping__c.isCreateable() ||
                !Schema.sObjectType.inscor__Customer_Quote__c.isUpdateable()) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('You do not have permission to update these records.');
        }
        insert dsamList;
        update cqList;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('An error occurred: '+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This removes the need to database.rollback on error, and will enable your code to use proper error handling on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestions. There is a day where I will make the exception handling change but today is not that day :)